# Get an article summary from the MediaWiki API

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I am looking for a mediawiki api using which I can get short description about any query string. For example , if I search for Nicolas Cage then it should return the short description for him.

I tried http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?%20format=json&action=query&titles=Nicolas%20Cage&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

I am not sure if prop=revisions is right. My intention is to get a short description on the final version of the page.

Also I need another api which can give the link of the wikipedia page (web / mobile) from the query string. i.e. For Nicolas Cage, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_cage should be returned.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no such thing as a page summary in MediaWiki by default,but you can get the first  paragraph of a page like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Nicolas_Cage&prop=text&section=0
   If the wiki has the extension [PageSummaries](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageSummaries) installed, you can use that to get exactly what you are asking for (like in [this example](http://www.unifiedrepublicofstars.com/wiki/api.php?action=parse&prop=text&page=Ivan_Boldyrev) from the extension description page).
2. To find pages matching a string, you use the open search function, like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=Nicolas%20cage&namespace=0

edit: @Bergi point out in the comments that open search also gives a summary of the page. I had somehow missed that.

Comment: +1. The [Opensearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch) will even give you an excerpt in its `<description>` node

Comment: With a `action=query` one could also use `&prop=extracts` to get more control of the length of the extract.

Answer (score 1):

Say, you want to get the summary of a search string Nicolas Cage.

Step 1. Get the page id: 
 "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=Nicolas%20Cage&format=json&srlimit=1"
Step 2. Use this page id to get section 0 of the page: 
"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&section=0&pageid=21111&prop=text&format=json"
Step 3. Parse as per requirements.
Step 3 extended for Python: Use BeautifulSoup for target tags and get_text() gives plaintext.
use rvprop to get latest revision, further go through mediaWIKI documentation.

Alternate Solution:
Step 1. Get page title using step 1 above. 
Step 2. Use the title as follows: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Nicolas%20Cage