# Query wikipedia

Tags: nlp, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I would like to query two or three terms in order to locate them in Wikipedia´s entries. Specifically, I´m trying to see if some terms get repeated in the first paragraphs (abstract) across entries. Could be direct or through dbpedia. Thanks

Comment: using what language? Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Could be in python or in SPARQL. This is an example from another stackoverflow user:SELECT ?uri ?txt WHERE {
                  ?uri rdfs:label ?txt .
                  ?txt bif:contains "'Egypt' AND 'Pyramid'" .
                 }   The problem is that it just returns those keywords found on catebory labels. I would like to find all the documents that contain both keywords in the text or abstract.

Answer (score 2):

Using Mediawiki API you can find articles that contain those keywords.
Try the [API:Search](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) documentation.

For doing what you want to do, also, you'd probably need to find the articles that have those keywords and then parse the text to check if they are in the first paragraphs.

With this:

```
?action=parse&page=Nicolas_Cage&prop=text&section=0
```

you can get the HTML of the first section of a page (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806962/get-an-article-summary-from-the-mediawiki-api)).